# php make array in array depending array value using function or class

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, sorting

I want to get output of first array to second array using php function or php class-
Here I should include that-

> 1. "deli" key's value "|" is separator of "name" key's value.
> 2. If "attr" key's value '32' in array,then this array has children and add children in "title".

```
$Y=array(array('name' => "Family1",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family2",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family2|Parents1",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family2|Parents3",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family2|Parents3|Children",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family2|Parents3|Children|ChildOfChild",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family4",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family4|Child",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|"));

$Y2=array(array('name' => "Family1",'title' => "Family1",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family2",'title' => "Family2",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|",'child' =>     array('name' => "Family2|Parents1",'title' => "Parents1",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family2|Parents3",'title' => "Parents3",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|",'child' =>   array('name' => "Family2|Parents3|Children",'title' => "Children",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|",'child' =>    array('name' => "Family2|Parents3|Children|ChildOfChild",'title' => "ChildOfChild",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|")))),array('name' => "Family3",'title' => "Family3",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|"),array('name' => "Family4",'title' => "Family4",'attr' => array(32,8),'deli' => "|",'child' => array('name' => "Family4|Child",'title' => "Child",'attr' => array(64,8),'deli' => "|")));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This may also help clarify your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Nigel Ren. Can you help me to getting PHP IMAP folder like [yandex mail](https://mail.yandex.com) folder system using [imap_getmailboxes](https://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-getmailboxes.php) function.

Comment: Mr. Nigel Ren, I want to just getthis simple html formating like [this picture](http://mamedul.000webhostapp.com/m/mail/CaptureTo.PNG) from [this json link](http://mamedul.000webhostapp.com/m/mail/mail.json) which is encoded json from php imap function and  as formulated as [php_getmailboxes](https://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-getmailboxes.php).